# Hive query: Is there a way to use UDTF with `cluster by`?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Solved:

It turns out to be a mistake in my UDTF.  I find out a fix but I don't quite understand why it worked.  At the beginning when I was implementing the UDTF, Eclipse suggested that `initialize` is deprecated.  But I got error if I skip it, so I implemented it anyway.  I put a variable initialization in that method, guessing init is only to be done once.  The jar worked for some simpler scenarios, but if I were to use the UDTF output with a UDF, then use the UDF output to do something, like the cheating `cluster by` or `insert`, I got the previously mentioned error.  The engineer friend of mine found out that the `initialize` actually got executed more than once.  So I just put the initialization in `process`, with a `if` checking if the variable is null, and init it if is.  Then everything works fine, my cheat also worked.  Still, if someone can give me an explanation, I would be most grateful.

---

Following is my original question:

---

I know I'm not supposed to use `cluster by` after UDTF, so `select myudtf("stringValue") cluster by rand()` wouldn't work.

But since my udtf outputs 7000+ and growing rows every hour, so I really need to distribute the subsequent processing to all my hadoop cluster slave units.

And I imagine I don't get that without using `cluster by rand()`, so I tried the following cheat:

First I wrap the result up with an other table, `select key from (select myudtf("stringValue") as key) t limit 1;` and it gives correct result,

```
OK
some/key/value/string
Time taken: 0.035 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Then I add the `cluster by` part, `select key from (select myudtf("stringValue") as key) t cluster by rand() limit 1`, then I get error:

```
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive ...
....

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_....

URL:
  http:....
....
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: tried to access class sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionContextImpl from class sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionContextImplConstructorAccess

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

I did this trying to cheat hive to treat the temporary table `t` as a "normal" table which I can apply `cluster by` to, hoping that it will distribute the work load to all the hadoop slaves, but unfortunately hive is clever enough to see through my poorly attempted trick.

So, could some one please help me to clarify my mis-conceptions, or give me some hint of the correct way to do this?

FYI I asked help from a highly experienced engineering guy in my company, and he thinks it maybe a deeper system level bug, he tried to trace the problem for 20 something minutes before he left work, he did find some lib version issues but couldn't fix the problem after all.  ...And I just guess it must be something I did wrongly.

Comment: I think my concern boils down to if `select myudtf("stringValue")`, a map only job, is processed on a single node or is it also distributed to all slaves.  Do I have to have a shuffle operation like `cluster by` or `join` to tell hive to distribute the workload.  If so, how should I do it, or I don't need to do anything and hive internally takes care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a mistake in my UDTF. I find out a fix but I don't quite understand why it worked. At the beginning when I was implementing the UDTF, Eclipse suggested that `initialize` is deprecated. But I got error if I skip it, so I implemented it anyway. I put a variable initialization in that method, guessing init is only to be done once. The jar worked for some simpler scenarios, but if I were to use the UDTF output with a UDF, then use the UDF output to do something, like the cheating `cluster by` or `insert`, I got the previously mentioned error. The engineer friend of mine found out that the initialize actually got executed more than once. So I just put the initialization in `process`, with a `if` checking if the variable is null, and init it if is. Then everything works fine, my cheat also worked. Still, if someone can give me a more specific explanation, I would be most grateful.